# vb.net - Encode string to UTF-8

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, utf-8

I've made a class to encode a string

```
Public Class UTF8
    Public Shared Function encode(ByVal str As String)
        Dim utf8Encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
        Dim encodedString() As Byte

        encodedString = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(str)

        Return encodedString.ToString()
    End Function
End Class
```

Return encodedString.ToString() always returns "System.Byte[]". How could I get the real UTF-8 String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [UTF8.GetString(Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getstring.aspx) method.

Comment: There's no point, that just returns the original string.  A utf8 encoded string has to stay in a byte array.

Comment: And how could I check if a string IS utf-8? Thank you.

Comment: You missed the point.  That's not possible, a string is always encoded in utf16 in .NET.  If you think you got a string that contains utf8 then you surely do not, it is very likely to have gotten mangled in the process.

Comment: @Hans your statement is incorrect, there are differenet .net encoding methods for UTF8, UTF16 and UTF32. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.90).aspx Your comment should be deleted as inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

We can check if a string is UTF-8 by examining the string BOM value. This is the correct code sample:

```
Public Shared Function encode(ByVal str As String) As String
    'supply True as the construction parameter to indicate
    'that you wanted the class to emit BOM (Byte Order Mark)
    'NOTE: this BOM value is the indicator of a UTF-8 string
    Dim utf8Encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(True)
    Dim encodedString() As Byte

    encodedString = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(str)

    Return utf8Encoding.GetString(encodedString)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub BtnClearText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClearText.Click
        TxtEncodedValue.Text = ""
        TxtNormalValue.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnEncode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEncode.Click
        Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TxtNormalValue.Text)
        TxtEncodedValue.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(byt)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDecode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDecode.Click
        Dim b As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(TxtEncodedValue.Text)
        TxtNormalValue.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

 
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].