# Check if a string is UTF-8

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible? I want to check if a string is utf-8 encoded.

UPDATE: So, the problem is: I have a php webservice. This webservice has a method that receives a string. I'm trying to pass a VB.NET JSON string to this webservice. json_decode always returns an error, saying that the string is not utf-8. If I pass the string and convert it using PHP utf8_encode, the accents get wrong! How could I solve that?

Comment: How does your string look like? `byte[]`?

Comment: I've made this, but i don't know if it's alright: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035380/vb-net-encode-string-to-utf-8 . Thank you.

Comment: The only way I think will work without any third party tools is to just iterate over the byte array and test if it matches a known encoding. A great article with this is posted @ http://www.mobzystems.com/code/detecting-text-encoding.aspx

Comment: A `System.String` is never UTF-8. It's UTF-16. Only the byte representation of a string can be UTF-8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine a string's encoding in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025332/determine-a-strings-encoding-in-c-sharp)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915633/determine-textfile-encoding

Comment: This article ^^^ applies only when input byte[] has a Preamble setup already. Pretty much that is when the creator of the stream "tells" you what the encoding is. Is not answering the OP question.