# Decode text from .txt file asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, decode

I have a directory in my web proyect with this file:

```
home.text
```

and inside the home.txt file I have this text:

```
ESPAÑA_BOLSA.xlsx
```

So I have this code in vb.net to extract the text from the .txt file:

```
Public Shared Function GetTextFromTXT() As String       
        Dim FilePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/excel/home.txt")
        ' Creates instance of StreamReader class
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FilePath)
        ' Finally, loads file to string
        Dim FileContent As String = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString
  Return FileContent
End Function
```

but with this code I get this result in Filecontent:

```
ESPA�A_BOLSA.xlsx
```

So I use this line to try to decode the text, but is not work:

```
  FileContent = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(FileContent)
```

The result should be this from the Filecontent string:

```
 ESPAÑA_BOLSA.xlsx
```

What I'm doing wrong? thanks, I accept suggestions

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915633/determine-textfile-encoding)

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution

Comment: It's probably an encoding issue as mentioned below, but you should also change your code, you created a memory leak by not closing your stream reader. Research "Using-statements" in VB for the cleanest solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`StreamReader` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `Encoding`, and pass in the appropriate encoding - otherwise it will default to using UTF-8.  `Encoding.Default` may work, otherwise you will need to use specific encoding.  I don't know how your file is encoded, so can't tell you the exact value you need, but you could try:

```vb
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FilePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
' or, as an example - you may need a different encoding
Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(FilePath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"))
```

Comment: Your code works perfect to me, than you very much for your time :-)