# Description encoding error with YouTube API v3

Tags: encoding, youtube-api

I've successfully created a project to upload YouTube videos programmatically through VB.NET, and it has worked for some weeks now until today.

I'm having trouble uploading videos which contain German umlauts in the description field: as soon as I try to upload such a video, I'm getting the following `WebException`:

> System.Exception: Bad Request ---> System.Net.WebException:

If I remove the description field or the umlauts, the upload works without problems.

I've also tried to UTF8-encode the string, but not successfully.

The error just occurred today...

Comment: Same thing happened to me, with the Java client. It worked with accented characters in the description. It used to work on Jun 25, it started failing from Jun 26 onwards.

Comment: [I've opened a ticket for the YouTube team](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4827), with no answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same error today: it was occurring with Japanese and Korean while English and Chinese/Taiwanese were fine.

At first, I thought it was utf8 related. A few hours later, I found out YouTube does not rely on [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2). You can get [their list there](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/i18nLanguages/list).

Replacing 'jp' to 'ja' and 'kr' to 'ko' in *defaultAudioLanguage* fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the special characters can't be parsed through an http request. So why not write a converter that searches for the umlaut characters and converts them to characters that can be parsed, for example

```
ä -> a
ë -> e
ö -> o
û -> u
etc...
```

That would be the simplest way to do it, although you might be able to get away with switching to some encoding that will automatically remove them for you, then switch back to default to build the request.

I would play around with the different encodings that you can use in VB.Net and see what you can get.

Here is some documentation on what encoding there is available to .Net, how to UTF-8 encode strings in VB .Net, and the Encoding class reference for VB .Net:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx

[vb.net - Encode string to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035380/vb-net-encode-string-to-utf-8)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Hello, as I wrote the posts worked until today - and it should not be a problem to send special characters trough a http request if they're encoded correctly.

Comment: Right, but there is no telling whether or not the back end of the YouTube API has been modified which has broken the capability to receive special characters. It may have nothing to do with Encoding.

Comment: But there should be an official way to add special characters in those fields - I mean I am able to add a sentence like #Hello@ä to a manual update trough the website...

Comment: Like i said, the API back end may no longer support special characters, there really isn't a more official way that using the official Google YouTube API...

Comment: Funny thing is - as of today it works again (with special characters) - so hopefully this was an error and not a feature change :).

Comment: UPDATE: for hours after it worked - it stopped working again (#@!) :).

Comment: sorry, FOUR hours - not for hours

Comment: David, YouTube supports accented characters. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to write video titles or descriptions in languages other than English. Their _backend_ supports it, as evidenced by the fact you can login and edit a video description with accented chars. The _API itself_ seems broken as of Jun 25.

Comment: Does anybody have news on this issue?