# videos.update returns invalidVideoMetadata when editing description of some videos

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to edit a video's description. In the `videos.update` endpoint [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#request-body), it is mentioned that all sub-fields of the `snippet` field must be present, otherwise their values will be deleted. I'm doing it like this:

```
snippet = yt.videos().list(id='…', part='snippet').execute()['items'][0]['snippet']
snippet['description'] = "…"
yt.videos().update(part='snippet', body={'id': '…', 'snippet': snippet}).execute()
```

For some of my videos, this works, but for others, it returns a `400 Bad Request` with the reason `invalidVideoMetadata`. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.update) for this error only mentions either the title or the category ID missing, but I have checked, and they are both in the `dict` (and I'm not modifying them).

Could you please tell me under which other circumstances an `invalidVideoMetadata` error is returned, and what I should to with my `snippet` to not encounter this error?

Minimum working example:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_id.json', scopes=('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',))
credentials = flow.run_local_server()

with build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials) as yt:
    # this works
    snippet = yt.videos().list(id='r9oZaLgHryE', part='snippet').execute()['items'][0]['snippet']
    snippet['description'] = "test"
    yt.videos().update(part='snippet', body={'id': 'r9oZaLgHryE', 'snippet': snippet}).execute()

    # this doesn't
    snippet = yt.videos().list(id='HS118OE-EdM', part='snippet').execute()['items'][0]['snippet']
    snippet['description'] = "test"
    yt.videos().update(part='snippet', body={'id': 'HS118OE-EdM', 'snippet': snippet}).execute()
```

Comment: "Could you please tell me under which other circumstances an invalidVideoMetadata error is returned, and what I should to with my snippet to not encounter this error?" Well, did you try to *test it*? For example, log the metadata that you try each time, and compare what it looks like in the successful vs. failing cases? "it is mentioned that all sub-fields of the snippet field must be present" Did the documentation happen to list what those sub-fields are?

Answer (score 0):

The snippets of the videos that don't work include the field `'defaultAudioLanguage': 'zxx'`. This field is supposed to indicate the language that is spoken in the video's default audio track, and I left it blank for a video where no speech occurs. Apparently in the API this is represented by the language `zxx`, which, however, isn't a valid language (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020027).

Since the documentation for the `videos.update` endpoint only lists a few fields that must be included in the request's snippet, and `defaultAudioLanguage` is not one of them, I changed my code to explicitly set them instead of copying over all of the old snippet's values:

```
snippet_new = {
    'title': snippet_old['title'],
    'description': "test",
    'tags': snippet_old['tags'],
    …
}
```

Now it works, but this solution has the disadvantage that, if new snippet fields become editable in the `videos.update` endpoint, my code will delete them by default instead of keeping their old values.